# When I run cordova build android I have this error: com.google.android.gms plugin dependencies error

Tags: cordova

I have get this error

The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.5.0,16.5.0], [16.4.0,16.4.0]], but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: This works for me:

Add below properties in " \platforms\android\project.properties " file

cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8

cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0

cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+

cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1